# Direct addressing of cell in apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to modify an existing xlsm file with apache POI.

As I only have to change single cells I don't want to loop over the whole sheet, but all the examples I have found so far suggest to loop over all the rows and over all cells in a row, checking if the current row/col-index matches the one to be changed.

Is there no "random access" mode to get a single cell by its coordinates directly? Event the promising [getCell method of the CellUtil class](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html#getCell(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row,%20int)) needs a row object instead of just an integer coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

The Excel file format is a (normally) sparse file format, so unused + unstyled rows and cells are normally skipped from the file. So, you do need to check for null values when fetching rows and cells. But, other than that, you can fetch cells pretty much directly. You can use the [CellReference class](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html) to turn an Excel-style set of co-ordinates (eg B3) into a POI-style one (eg row=2, column=1), then fetch

```
CellReference ref = new CellReference("B3");

Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xls"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Row r = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
if (r == null) {
   // Handle this whole row being empty
} else {
   Cell c = r.getCell(ref.getCol(), Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
   if (c == null) {
      // Handle this cell being empty
   } else {
      // Do something with the cell
   }
}
```

Depending on how you want to handle missing rows or cells, you can make it shorter, but that'll be specific to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You get first the row from the sheet and then get the cell at x,y from it:

```
Row myRow = getRow(int x, sheet);
Cell myCell = getCell(myRow, int y);
```

Comment: This is the way I'm doing it at the moment, it just strikes me as odd that there is no method on the Sheet class to get cells directly.